# Find parametric and symmetric equations of a line passing through two points?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find both the parametric and symmetric equations of a line passing through two points. This is for a study exam, so exact answers are not as helpful as detailed solutions.

$P(3,-1,1);$
$Q(-2,1,1)$

I found the points vectors then put them with respect to t:
$$r(t) = (3,-1,1)+t(-2,1,1)$$

Then set each x,y,z to t, which should be the parametric equation:
$$x(t)=3-2t$$

$$y(t)=-1+t$$

$$z(t)=1+t$$

Then to find the symmetric equation I set the points equal to giving me this:
$\frac{(3-x)}{2}=1+y=z-1$

I am having trouble finding if I went about this the wrong way, primarily when creating the vectors and putting them in the equation for a line with respect to $t.$

Comment: The correct equation does not have a term $t<-2,1,1>$, but rather $t$ multiplied by the displacement vector $P-Q$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your parameterization is not correct.

A parameterization of a line has the form $r(t)= P + t D$ where $P$ is a vector "touching" the line and $D$ is a *direction vector* for the line.

Given two points on the line, $P$ and $Q$, the equation $r(t) = P+ t Q$ is not the correct parameterization. This is where you are in error.  So, instead of using $Q$ as you did, use the displacement vector from $P$ to $Q$.  In your case, this would be
$$
Q-P = (-2,1,1) - (3,-1,1) =\bigl(-2-3 , 1-(-1), 1-1 \bigr)=(-5,2,0).
$$
The parameterization is then
$$
r(t)=(3,-1,1)+t(-5,2,0).
$$
(And don't forget to give a range of values for $t$.)

Your procedure for finding the symmetric equations looks ok.

Comment: How is the symmetric equation correct? There is no value "t" that equates to (-2, 1, 1).

Comment: Sir, range of $t$ is $0≤t≤1$ or $t\in\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score -3):

Give a vector parametric equation for the line through the point (−4,1,1)(−4,1,1) that is parallel to the line ⟨−4−2t,2,−1−t⟩⟨−4−2t,2,−1−t⟩